# Does anyone know how to automate WAFL reallocate on a Netapp Filer 3240 / 3220

Tags: powershell, vbscript, netapp

We have 4 x NetApp filers, each with around 50x VOLs. We've been experience performance issues & tracked it down to how fragmented the data is. We've run some measures (all coming back over 7+) and have been gradually manually running the WAFL reallocates (starting with our VMStores) which is improving the fragmentation level to around 3/4.

As ever - time is short and was wondering if anyone had a script which could handle this process? Preferably Powershell or VBScript.

(we have the DataOnTap CMDlets installed & enabled)

I know you can schedule scans but you cant seem to tell the filer to only run one at a time.

I'd ideally like a script which would:

+Pull a csv of volumes
+Measure each volume sequentially, only starting the next measure when the previous has completed, recording the scoring
+Then Reallocate each volume sequentially, only starting the next Reallocate when the previous has completed, recording the new scoring

For your reference:

https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196890/html/man1/na_reallocate.1.html

Any help / guidance in this matter would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 7-mode or cDOT?

Anyway, I only know Powershell. The script shouldn't be long and it would go as something like this:

- connect the netapp (using connect-nacontroller / connect-nccontroller)
- getting all the volumes (using get-navol / get-ncvol)
- get the measurement for each volume (either using foreach or perhaps the command could be run once and give the information for all the volumes)
- export the output to csv (using export-csv)
- a foreach loop iterating on all the volumes:

  ```
  - if volume is fragmented behind a given threshold
          - run the reallocation (I do not know which command needs to be used)
  ```
- If you want this thing to run eternally just put it all under a while loop, if you are going to schedule this you should rerun the checks to get a new csv with the new measurements.

Disclaimer:
I am not familiar with the reallocation process nor with it's powershell command behaviors. The post should give you pretty much the things to be done but I was only using common sense.
Perhaps the command for reallocation only start the reallocation process and let it run at the background - resulting in all of the reallocation to run simultaneously. If so, a while loop is needed inside the if statement using another command to report the status until it is completed.
You should try to run this on a single volume and then a list including few volumes in order to make sure it runs the way you want it to.

Comment: This is an excellent, thanks so much. apologies for the delay in upvotes & response.

Comment: I Hope it helped. Please let me know which command was the reallocation one if you actually did that script in powershell